# Regular expression to validate delimiter separated numbers

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I need a regular expression to validate the an input from a form with those values

for example:

```
123, 444,231, 2231 ...
```

what is the best way regular expression for that cycle?

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: What format the values should have?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to match on the numbers?

Use this:

```
([0-9]{1,}+){1,}
```

That will match each of the values.

Comment: But, personally, I wouldn't use a regex for this. C# has a native way to split based on string delimiters, in this case, a comma.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you the following.
`^(\s*\d+\s*,?)+$` it takes into consideration the possiblity of leading and trailing spaces of your CSV values

**Edit**

I modified the expression and here is the new version: `^(\s*\d+\s*,)*(\s*\d+\s*){1}$` It wil not fail in commented case.

Answer (score 1):

```
([1-9]\d{2,3},\s*)  //first one digit 1-9, followed by 2 to 3 other digits,a comma and zero or one whitespace
{0,}            //This pattern may occour 0 or more times, followed by...
([1-9]\d{2,3})  // one of these number without the trailing comma, only once.
```

Comment: @Tomek, that's because he didn't give any example where there were no commas between the numbers. ([1-9]\d{2,3}\s*,*\s*) will work. It won't work with multiple spaces neither, because that was not in the example given. Change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of requirements is bit vague, but this might be what you want:

```
^(\s*\d+\s*(?(?=,\s*\d),|))+$
```

It validates the sequence of numbers delimited by "," allowing leading and trailing white characters and not starting and ending by ","